# How do you create a string of numbers using repeat zone

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I iterate from 1 to 3 instead of three 1's? I want the value going into the String to Curve node to update with each iteration. I know how to do it with the Simulation zone by combining it with a Scene Time node and feeding the frame number into the string to curve node but I don't know how to do it with the Repeat zone.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple, just mantain a counter - you can even join strings instead of geometry to only convert string to curves once (and get the benefit of kerning, word wrapping etc.)

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know you could create a counter, but I figured it out. Thank you!